# Remove all html tags and javascript tags using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, regex, tags

How can I remove all html tags and script tags? Please consider also short tags like unclosed tags

```
<script>blah...</script>
<body> aaa<b>bbb</body>
```

This should return

```
aaa bbb
```

notice that all the contents inside the script tag is ignored. Can you experts please help me to make this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: why wouldn't strip_tags() do the thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this function from [phpjs project](http://phpjs.org/functions/strip_tags:535):

```
function strip_tags (input, allowed) {
    // http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net
    // +   original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   improved by: Luke Godfrey
    // +      input by: Pul
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
    // +      input by: Alex
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +      input by: Marc Palau
    // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +      input by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   bugfixed by: Eric Nagel
    // +      input by: Bobby Drake
    // +   bugfixed by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
    // +   bugfixed by: Tomasz Wesolowski
    // +      input by: Evertjan Garretsen
    // +    revised by: Rafał Kukawski (http://blog.kukawski.pl/)
    // *     example 1: strip_tags('<p>Kevin</p> <br /><b>van</b> <i>Zonneveld</i>', '<i><b>');
    // *     returns 1: 'Kevin <b>van</b> <i>Zonneveld</i>'
    // *     example 2: strip_tags('<p>Kevin <img src="someimage.png" onmouseover="someFunction()">van <i>Zonneveld</i></p>', '<p>');
    // *     returns 2: '<p>Kevin van Zonneveld</p>'
    // *     example 3: strip_tags("<a href='http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net'>Kevin van Zonneveld</a>", "<a>");
    // *     returns 3: '<a href='http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net'>Kevin van Zonneveld</a>'
    // *     example 4: strip_tags('1 < 5 5 > 1');
    // *     returns 4: '1 < 5 5 > 1'
    // *     example 5: strip_tags('1 <br/> 1');
    // *     returns 5: '1  1'
    // *     example 6: strip_tags('1 <br/> 1', '<br>');
    // *     returns 6: '1  1'
    // *     example 7: strip_tags('1 <br/> 1', '<br><br/>');
    // *     returns 7: '1 <br/> 1'

       allowed = (((allowed || "") + "")
          .toLowerCase()
          .match(/<[a-z][a-z0-9]*>/g) || [])
          .join(''); // making sure the allowed arg is a string containing only tags in lowercase (<a><b><c>)
       var tags = /<\/?([a-z][a-z0-9]*)\b[^>]*>/gi,
           commentsAndPhpTags = /<!--[\s\S]*?-->|<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]*?\?>/gi;
       return input.replace(commentsAndPhpTags, '').replace(tags, function($0, $1){
          return allowed.indexOf('<' + $1.toLowerCase() + '>') > -1 ? $0 : '';
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not expert in regexp

...But by this following prog I'm replace

> only Html tag

:

```
<?php 
$html= "<script>blah...</script>
<body> aaa<b>bbb</body>";
echo str_ireplace("<*>",'',$html);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do not use regęx!

With jQuery, you can do something like this:

```
function notags(data){
    return $(data).filter(function(){ return !$(this).is('script'); }).text();
}

alert(notags('<script>blah...</script><body> aaa<b>bbb</body>'));
```

Comment: The problem with the .text() is it won't display the shortend html's just like what I have said I must include it... Take for example "<b>abc" this must return abc. One reason why I need to use regex.